# Help in debugging PL/SQL package?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, plsql

I have a problem in my asp.net MVC application.

I have a wrapper class for PL/SQL package. And I have to save screen changes to database through package call. While the process its not throwing any exception or error.

How do I debug the package to find where the problem is?

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure the procedures and functions in the package don't swallow exceptions - i.e. get rid of any `WHEN OTHERS THEN null;` exception handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Oracle's SQL Developer and use it to [debug](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/sqldev%5Fobe/plsql%5Fdebug/plsql%5Fdebug.htm) your package.

If debugging is not allowed in your DB, [this article](http://www.bestremotedba.com/toad-debug-option-not-enabled-for-oracle-10g-database/) could help you.

If you think that an exception is thrown in your PL/SQL source, make sure that there is no `WHEN OTHERS` without `RAISE`. You could also try to remove some other exception handlings temporary while testing your package.

Answer (score 0):

You can download : SQL * Plus, http://www.oracle.com/.../tech/sql_plus/index.html (it's free).
From SQL  * Plus you'll be able to debug your package from the command line by doing a :

```
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: That will show compilation errors after compiling, but not run-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would test the package directly using sqlplus via `set serveroutput on` combined with `dbms_output.put_line` calls in your package.  This will let you see what is happening in your package when given various inputs.  This should at least let you isolate whether there is a problem in the PL/SQL code or in the ASP.Net caller.